Attribute shading doesn't work in Cycles
I have this scene where I fracture the earth and assign a distance to each piece called heat
I then scale it to between 0-1 and pass that to a color ramp and color the pieces.
This works exactly as expected in the preview.


However, in cycles the attribute becomes 0 by default. And everything has the same value.

The geonode setup is this simple.

This feels like a bug. Can anyone think of why this wouldn't work in cycles?

Do you have a single object with islands, or one object per piece ?

One object per piece.

It would be much easier if you could upload your file. Finding a solution by just recreating something similar to your setup might suffer from having different properties which do not apply in your scene - which is why none of the proposed solutions in the answer might not work for you eventually.

The interesting here would be, because you give no information about it in your question: How have you fractured the earth and how are the pieces moving?

(Using Blender 3.6.8)
Final (?) proposal
It seems that "heat" is an attribute of the Cycles render engine. Changing "heat" to "Heat" is solving the different behaviour compared to the Eevee render engine:


Resources: 

First proposal
Storing the attribute in Instance domain, instead of Point domain, yields the same behaviour with Eevee and Cycles render engines, using the following setup:



Resources: 

Second proposal
Following is a proposal working in Point domain (dark green part of the GN graph) and in Instance domain (dark red part of the GN graph):



Resources: 

I will probably delete first and second proposal, if the third one is validated...

This will not work. Since I am using two materials on my objects. Instances do not support multiple material assignments. Also this doesn't explain why it won't show up in Cycles.
I would be curious to see if you can assign a second material to the tops of all of those cubes and still get the correct result tho. Would narrow down the issue

@TheJeran: Are you talking about what I labelled "Final (?) proposal" ? Or about the "First" and "Second" proposals, that might be removed ? Could you try and change "heat" into "Heat", and let us know the outcome ?

It seems maybe that "heat" is something like "reserved word" in cycles, when I changed it to "heat1" it worked (I used "density" in my project and it does not work either, so I chaged it to "density1" and now it works).

The are probably builtin attributes from smoke domains for fire and particle simulations
